# The server is not receiving the message of the client

Tags: java, sockets

I'm new to Java socket programming and I'm trying to write a program which is supposed to be run on 2 separate controllers. I have written a thread which is used as the communication class.

I have defined a flag called SFlag so that when the value of this flag is changed to 1 anywhere in my program, the corresponding controller will send a hello message to the other controller through sendPackets() function. The other controller will receive this message through **ReceivePackets** class and it will print the result. Here is the code:

```
// My UDP communication class
    public class MainConn implements Runnable {

        // Sockets, 1 for sending, and one for receiving
        DatagramSocket socket1, socket2;

        // localIP
        private InetAddress localIP;
        private InetAddress leaderIP;

        // classes to run on separate Threads
        private ReceivePackets rcvThread;


        @Override
        public void run() {
            process();
        }

        public void process() {

            // initialize some parameters
            init1();

            // Make Thread for receiving packets and update counters from all
            // controller
            rcvThread = new ReceivePackets();
            Thread r = new Thread(rcvThread);
            r.start();

            sendPackets();
        }

        public void init1() {
            try {
                // create sockets
                String tempString = config.get("localPort");
                localPort = Integer.parseInt(tempString);
                logger.info("----------here is==========" +localPort);

                leaderIP = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
                logger.info("----------here is==========" +leaderIP);

                socket1 = new DatagramSocket(localPort); // for sending
                socket2 = new DatagramSocket(localPort + 1); // for receiving
            } catch (SocketException | UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        //*******************************************************

        public void sendPackets() {
            // will be used to begin sending message type II after 3*hello
            // period

            while (true) {
                try {

                    // if network not converged, send message type I, contains:
                    // type number (1) then
                    if (SFlag == 1) {               
                        logger.info("Sending the message");
                        String tempString = new String("Hello");

                        byte[] data = tempString.getBytes();                
                        DatagramPacket sentPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, tempString.length());
                        sentPacket.setAddress(leaderIP);
                        sentPacket.setPort(20222);
                        socket1.send(sentPacket);
                        SFlag = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        logger.info("Nothinggggggggggggg");
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(5000);// wait for Hello period

                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        class ReceivePackets implements Runnable {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        logger.info("---------------waiting------------------");
                        byte[] data = new byte[1000];
                        DatagramPacket receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                        socket2.receive(receivedPacket);
                        String senderIP = receivedPacket.getAddress().getHostAddress();
                        String senderPort = "" + receivedPacket.getPort();
                        String message = new String(data, 0, receivedPacket.getLength());
                        logger.info(message);

                        System.out.println("Received Message: "+message);
                        }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

When the value of SFlag is changed to 1, it seems that the first controller is sending the message ("Sending the message" is printed), but there seems to be a problem with receiving the message on the second controller, because the received message is not printed.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

**(1)** Since both threads rely on `SFlag` for communication, make sure it is declared with the `volatile` keyword:

```
private volatile int SFlag = 0;
```

The `volatile` keyword prevents the variable from being cached, so both threads will see the same value all the time. Besides that, reading and writing operations on `volatile` variables are atomic.

**(2)** You have a hardcoded port number in this line:

```
sentPacket.setPort(20222);
```

Make sure this is the port number used by the `ReceivePackets` thread. Ideally we should never have magic numbers mixed with the code. So you should move that port number to a separate variable or constant.

**(3)** In Java you shouldn't create a `String` with `new`. For example, this is bad practice:

```
String tempString = new String("Hello"); // bad practice
```

You should do:

```
String tempString = "Hello";
```

**My last piece of advice is: clean up your code**. You can look at Oracle's tutorial on sending and receiving datagram packets here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html